# Spring Batch exception Handling

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

Am currently working with spring batch for the first time. In spring batch i've set commit level to 1000 which gave me better performance but now I ve the issues in identifying the corrupt or exception item. We need to send mail update with the record line or item number with the exception data.

I tried item listener, chunk listener, step listener and job listener but am not able to figure out how to get those information from execution listener context while generating mail in job listener.  Am able to get the information about exception and not able to track which record has the issue and item count in the chunk. 
For example, if I have 1000 lines in file or db and commit level 100. If we have issue in 165 item. I need to get the line number as 165 in any listener so I can attach that in context to populate logging info to have a quick turn around time to fix the issue before reprocessing.
I Searched but I couldn't get suggestion or idea. I believe this will be a common problem in chunk commit greater than 1.  Please suggest the better way to handle.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to perform the checks that can cause an issue in the processor, and create an error item out of them which will get persisted to its own table/file. Some errors are unavoidable, and unfortunately you'll need to do manual debugging within that chunk.

Edit:
To find the commit range, you would need to preserve order. If using a `FlatFileItemReader`, it will store the line for you if your POJO implements `ItemCountAware`. If running against a DB, you'll want to make sure the query preserves order with an order by on the unique index. Then you'll be able to track the chunk down by checking where `read_count` from the `batch_step_execution` table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will fail the job for first occurred issue itself but in million record file for example if 1000th commit fails I can understand its 999*1000 +? ( I need this number)

Comment: Also I need to send Complete info to support team to have manual correction if required before restart. Turn around should be Asap

Comment: Thanks. Read count will be the whole number of commit level right if its 100...  Read count will be in multiples of 100..  Issue might be in 59 item. How do I get this 59 number (if possible data) in job execution listener

Answer (score 0):

You can enable [skipping](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/03/transactions-in-spring-batch-part-3-skip-and-retry/). Spring Batch processes each item of a chunk again in a separate transaction after a chunk fails due to a skippable exception. It detects the item that caused the exception in this way.